# Capturing a window on Win 10 without WinRT

Tags: c++, winapi, gpu, dxgi

I am trying to capture a window (not a part of the screen) using swap chains on a Windows 10 machine *without* WinRT.

I ran a project with WinRT and it worked, suggesting my graphics card is capable of capturing windows.

However, I'm not getting any errors, but `pStagingTexture` is blank and `imageData` is full of zeroes. I tested `SaveTextureAsPng()` with the Windows Duplication API, capturing a screen rather than a window, and it worked, so `SaveTextureAsPng()` is likely not the issue.

I also tried capturing windows that are visible and minimized, but no luck. I have tried different surface flags. I know I can use GDI+ (I think), but I want to use the GPU (like a Quadro P4000, driver 472.98). I would also prefer that it works with C++14.

```
bool CaptureWindow(HWND hwnd, LPCWSTR filepath)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    ID3D11Device* pDevice = nullptr;
    IDXGIDevice* pDXGIDevice = nullptr;
    IDXGIAdapter* pDXGIAdapter = nullptr;
    IDXGIOutput* pOutput = nullptr;
    IDXGIOutput1* pOutput1 = nullptr;
    IDXGIOutputDuplication* pOutputDuplication = nullptr;
    IDXGIFactory2* pFactory = nullptr;
    ID3D11Texture2D* pStagingTexture = nullptr;
    ID3D11DeviceContext* pImmediateContext = nullptr;

    RECT rect;
    UINT width, height;

    if (GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect))
    {
        width = rect.right - rect.left;
        height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "hwnd doesn't have any dimensions" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    hr = D3D11CreateDevice(
        nullptr,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        nullptr,
        0,
        nullptr,
        0,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &pDevice,
        nullptr,
        &pImmediateContext);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create D3D11 device." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    hr = pDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pDXGIDevice));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to retrieve DXGI device." << std::endl;
        pDevice->Release();
        return false;
    }

    hr = pDXGIDevice->GetAdapter(&pDXGIAdapter);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to retrieve DXGI adapter." << std::endl;
        pDXGIDevice->Release();
        pDevice->Release();
        return false;
    }

    hr = pDXGIAdapter->EnumOutputs(0, &pOutput);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to enumerate DXGI output." << std::endl;
        pDXGIAdapter->Release();
        pDXGIDevice->Release();
        pDevice->Release();
        return false;
    }

    // Get the DXGI factory
    hr = pDXGIAdapter->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory2), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pFactory));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to retrieve DXGI factory." << std::endl;
        pOutput->Release();
        pDXGIAdapter->Release();
        pDXGIDevice->Release();
        pDevice->Release();
        return false;
    }

    // Create swap chain description
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapChainDesc = {};
    swapChainDesc.Width = width;
    swapChainDesc.Height = height;
    swapChainDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    swapChainDesc.Stereo = false;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;
    swapChainDesc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH;
    swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
    swapChainDesc.AlphaMode = DXGI_ALPHA_MODE_UNSPECIFIED;
    swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;

    // Create swap chain
    IDXGISwapChain1* pSwapChain = nullptr;
    hr = pFactory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(
        pDevice,
        hwnd,
        &swapChainDesc,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        &pSwapChain);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create swap chain." << std::endl;
        pFactory->Release();
        pOutput->Release();
        pDXGIAdapter->Release();
        pDXGIDevice->Release();
        pDevice->Release();
        return false;
    }

    // Get the back buffer
    ID3D11Texture2D* pBackBuffer = nullptr;
    hr = pSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pBackBuffer));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to get back buffer from swap chain." << std::endl;
        pSwapChain->Release();
        pFactory->Release();
        pOutput->Release();
        pDXGIAdapter->Release();
        pDXGIDevice->Release();
        pDevice->Release();
        return false;
    }

    ID3D11RenderTargetView* pRenderTargetView = nullptr;
    hr = pDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, nullptr, &pRenderTargetView);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create render target view" << std::endl;
        pBackBuffer->Release();
        pSwapChain->Release();
        pFactory->Release();
        pOutput->Release();
        pDXGIAdapter->Release();
        pDXGIDevice->Release();
        pDevice->Release();
        return false;
    }

    // Unbind the back buffer and staging texture
    pImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &pRenderTargetView, nullptr);
    pRenderTargetView->Release();

    // Create a staging texture
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc = {};
    textureDesc.Width = width;
    textureDesc.Height = height;
    textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
    textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
    textureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    textureDesc.BindFlags = 0; //D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET; // | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE

    hr = pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, nullptr, &pStagingTexture);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create staging texture." << std::endl;
        pBackBuffer->Release();
        pSwapChain->Release();
        pFactory->Release();
        pOutput->Release();
        pDXGIAdapter->Release();
        pDXGIDevice->Release();
        pDevice->Release();
        return false;
    }

    // Copy the back buffer to the staging texture
    pImmediateContext->CopyResource(pStagingTexture, pBackBuffer);

    pImmediateContext->Flush();

    // Map the staging texture
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource = {};
    hr = pImmediateContext->Map(pStagingTexture, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &mappedResource);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to map staging texture." << std::endl;
        pStagingTexture->Release();
        pBackBuffer->Release();
        pSwapChain->Release();
        pFactory->Release();
        pOutput->Release();
        pDXGIAdapter->Release();
        pDXGIDevice->Release();
        pDevice->Release();
        return false;
    }

    // Save the mapped resource as an image
    //SaveMappedResourceAsPng(mappedResource, filename);
   

    // Calculate image size
    const UINT rowPitch = mappedResource.RowPitch;
    const UINT imageSize = rowPitch * textureDesc.Height;

    // Copy image data
    std::vector<BYTE> imageData(imageSize);
    memcpy(imageData.data(), mappedResource.pData, imageSize);

    // Unmap the staging texture
    pImmediateContext->Unmap(pStagingTexture, 0);

    SaveTextureAsPng(pStagingTexture, filepath);

    // Cleanup
    pStagingTexture->Release();
    pBackBuffer->Release();
    pSwapChain->Release();
    pFactory->Release();
    pOutput->Release();
    pDXGIAdapter->Release();
    pDXGIDevice->Release();
    pDevice->Release();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What's the specific reason you are trying to avoid using the Windows Runtime?

Comment: I am using a framework I wrote with a friend that competes with Windows RT. We want to add the screen sharing feature to our software and avoid scrapping the framework.

Comment: I cannot imagine a framework that would prevent you from spinning up a thread, and run a message loop on that thread. And that's all you need to make use of the [`Windows.Graphics.Capture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture) namespace.

Comment: We have our own threading/thread management api among other things that don't work together with winRT.